# Windows server 2012R2 RDS installed on Domain Controller will not uninstall

Tags: windows, domain-controller, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services

Knowing I had 90 days to figure out the licensing, I installed RDS. Seems I didn't need to as Administrators can log in anyway. Now it seems we don't want to buy any more licenses so I figured I would uninstall RDS and just use the administrator login angle. But on reboot the uninstall gets to about 90% then fails and I get the very scary continuous reboot situation. That seems to tire itself out after about 6 attempts.

Anyway - now the 90 days are up and I can't remote in at all.

[This link suggests it can't be uninstalled  because I created a broken Remote Desktop Server install by attempting to install on a domain controlle](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/bbf47aa2-8ae5-4f22-9827-afee5a11417a/install-remote-desktop-services-failed-on-windows-2012-server?forum=winserverTS)r, unaware that I shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You should have more than one domain controller in your network. And you shouldn't have anything else of consequence on this domain controller. So wipe the server and reinstall from scratch.

Comment: To add to this, if you *don't* have more than one DC, here's your chance.  Promote a new domain controller, transfer your FSMO roles and all that, demote this one, and rebuild it... without any additional roles or installations this time.  The only things that should go on a domain controller are DNS and Active Directory Domain Services... and some people do DHCP as well, which isn't particularly objectionable.